# Magento 1.8 - Update Mini Cart After AJAX POST

Tags: php, ajax, magento

On a custom page within Magento, I have a simple AJAX Post which passes a product ID to a php script:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/test/add_to_basket.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  success: function (data) {
  ,
  error: function (data) {
  }
});
```

Here is the add_to_basket php script:

```
$i = $_POST['i'];

require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

Mage::init('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));  

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();

$cart->addProduct($i, 1);

$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

$cart->save();
```

This works perfectly, however the mini cart doesn't update. I've read that I need to create a sections.xml file within etc/frontend like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="[frontName]/[ActionPath]/[ActionName]">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

However I'm not sure what the [frontName]/[ActionPath]/[ActionName] would be in my example. What is the best course of action?

Answer (score 0):

the most important thing – **ajax.php :**

```
require_once('/var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/app/Mage.php'); // ABSOLUTH PATH TO MAGE
umask(0);
Mage::app ();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));   // GET THE SESSION

$simbol= Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();  // GET THE CURRENCY SIMBOL
$store=Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();  // GET THE STORE CODE

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); //->getItemsCount();   

$ajtem=$_POST['item'];    // THIS IS THE ITEM ID
$items = $cart->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {   // LOOP
   if($item->getId()==$ajtem){  // IS THIS THE ITEM WE ARE CHANGING? IF IT IS:
       $item->setQty($_POST['qty']); // UPDATE ONLY THE QTY, NOTHING ELSE!
       $cart->save();  // SAVE
       Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
       echo '<span>';   
       if($store=='en')  echo $simbol;
       echo number_format($item->getPriceInclTax() * $_POST['qty'],2);
       if($store=='hr')  echo ' '.$simbol;
       echo '</span>';
       break;
   }

}

// THE REST IS updatTotalG FUNCTION WHICH IS CALLED AFTER AJAX IS COMPLETED 
// (UPDATE THE TOTALS)
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'function updateTotalG(){';
echo 'jQuery("#sveUkupno").html(\'';
echo '<strong><span>';
//echo 'JQuery(\'#sveUkupno\').html("<strong><span>';
if($store=='en')  echo $simbol;
echo number_format(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(),2);
//echo $simbol . ' </span></strong>");';
if($store=='hr')  echo ' '.$simbol;
echo " </span></strong>');";
echo '}   </script>';
```

> You can see that we detect the currency symbol in the script and the
>   store that is in use. At the end of the script it generates
>   updateTotalG script that we use for listing cart quantity value. The
>   value  comes from Magento.